# Is there a way to return the value for a tag from a XML based on a specific path in python?

Tags: python, xml

I have this XML

```
    <Body>
    <Batch_Number>2000</Batch_Number>
    <Total_No_Of_Batches>12312</Total_No_Of_Batches>
    <requestNo>1923</requestNo>
    <Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <Parent3>
                    <lastModifiedDateTime>2022-11-11T11:07:30.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
                    <purpose>NeverMore</purpose>
                    <endDate>9999-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
                    <createdDateTime>2019-06-06T06:32:16.000</createdDateTime>
                    <createdOn>2019-06-06T08:32:16.000</createdOn>
                    <address2>Forever street 21</address2>
                    <externalCode>code123</externalCode>
                    <lastModifiedBy>user2.thisUser</lastModifiedBy>
                    <lastModifiedOn>2039-06-11T13:07:30.000</lastModifiedOn>
                    <lastModifiedBy>MG</lastModifiedBy>
                    <PS>1234431</PS>
            </Parent3>
        </Parent2>
    </Parent1>
</Body>
```

Is there a way to return the value for lastModifiedBy for example where the path has this specific structure :

```
Body.Parent1.Parent2.Parent3.lastModifiedBy
```

Idealy, I would like to populate a dictionary with the child tag name and its value, for example :

```
dict[lastModifiedBy.tag] = lastModifiedBy.text
```

Comment: Last ``Body`` tag of your xml file missing.

Comment: Done, it didn't show beacuse of the way the code is displayed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from standart library for working with xml files.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("d.xml") # our xml file
root = tree.getroot()
```

And then you can access elements as indexes or you can use `root` like as a list:

```py
for i in root:
    print(i)
```

A XML element may have more than one child with same tag name (even you have two `lastModifiedBy` in the `Parent3`). This is why we use them like lists, they works like a list. So you shouldn't try to use them like dictionary.

I think you need to use [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). Like so:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("d.xml") # our xml file
root = tree.getroot()


s = root.findall(".Parent1/Parent2/Parent3/lastModifiedBy")

for i in s:
    print(i.text)
```

This gives you all `lastModifiedBy` elements in the `Parent3` element. You can access to any index if you want too, like this:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("d.xml") # our xml file
root = tree.getroot()


s = root.find(".Parent1/Parent2/Parent3/lastModifiedBy[1]") # first element with "lastModifiedBy" tag

print(s.text)
```

Comment: It works but if I look for `"Body.Parent1/Parent2/Parent3/lastModifiedBy[1]"` an error is returned `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
, any idea if I can give as input the whole location? Same situation if I try to get "Body/Batch_Number"

Comment: The `Body` itself is ``root`` variable, and `.` means *self* in XPath, so you should use ``".Parent1/Parent2/Parent3/lastModifiedBy[1]"``. I wrote that in my last example. More details is at here: [XPath documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)

Comment: Oh, ok, so there is no way for me to give the root location instead of "."?

Comment: What are you wanting as your root? The root is being variable which you are calling `find` or `findall` method of.